# How to access Google Calendar for above 50 users

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-authentication, google-api-python-client

I am implementing a Google calendar for multiple users with a user consent screen in my application with Oauth2.0 using python but facing issues with refresh token quota limit. I found a refresh token quota limit in google [docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration).
But they also mentioned that there is no limit for service account but service account is not for Google APIs on behalf of end-users, and user consent is sometimes required.

Is there any way to increase the refresh token quota limit? or
is there any way to implement with a service account

please help me how it can be done and what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You do need to worry

The documentation might be a bit confusing, but actually it is up to 50 refresh tokens per user!

So, if you have 1000 users, each of them can still use 50 refresh tokens - that is authenticate your application 50 times before the old tokens will be expired in favor of the newer ones.

Comment: Yes, document is confusing